# What is packages in Flutter assets inside pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter gallery sample code, and found following in `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/shrine_images/0-0.jpg
```

I tried to find out `packages` and `0-0.jpg` file in the project but couldn't find. Can anyone tell me what this package is all about and from where I am seeing images when running the app?

Answer (score 0):

Actually they have added a package

> flutter_gallery_assets: 0.1.9+2

Check it in pubspec.yaml dependencies, its a package so that you can use images from this package. So the pictures are from that package and they are just mentioning the image path from that package. Here is the package link they are using [click here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gallery_assets/versions/0.0.19)

Comment: Well I believe they are using `shrine_images` package for getting the images.